# AWS IOT Inconsistent results from multiple sequential requests

Tags: python, aws-iot

I'm writing a simple unittest which is running:

```
botocore.client.IoT.search_index(queryString='connectivity.connected:true')
```

My unittest simply connects a device, subscribes to MQTT, sends and receives a test message. This gives me reason to trust the device is truly online.

Sometimes my unit test passes, sometimes fails. When I come into a debugger and run the `search_index` command repeatedly I see inconsistent results between calls. Sometimes the device I just connected is online, sometimes it's not, after 20ish seconds the device appears to be consistently online.

I believe I'm probably getting responses from different servers and the propagation of the connected state between servers is simply delayed on the AWS side.

If my assessment is correct, then I want to know if there's anything I can do to force a consistent state between calls. Coding around this kind of inconsistent behavior is extremely error prone and almost certain to induce very hard to track bugs. Plus I don't trust that many other requests I'm making to AWS IOT are safe to rely on. In short I'm not going to do it, I'll find a better solution if there's no way to force AWS IOT to provide a consistent state between calls.

Answer (score 0):

Giving that you are unit testing your code, what you can do is mock `botocore.client.IoT.search_index` response. Verify the `patch` function from `unittest.mock` library (https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html). For your case it must be something like:

```
@patch('botocore.client.IoT')
def test(iotMockedClass):
    iotMockedClass.search_index.return_value = 'a fixed value that you must define'
    # ... your unit test case
```

It's also important to mention that unit tests should not depend on the environment, which must be replaced with mocks or stubs.

Comment: It's not the unittest that I'm concerned about, it's the inconsistent response from the server that is of concern. The fact that the unittest is failing is highlighting a problem that I feel needs to be addressed properly. I don't want to sidestep a legitimate problem just to make a unittest pass. I claim that `search_index` should return True from the server after I've sent and received a message. The fact that it's not immediately returning True is of concern, but the fact that the result is inconsistent between calls is of great concern.